# Updating List child color using setState is not working in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, setstate

Hi I was trying to add a new child to List using a existing child itself in the list.
I tried to achieve this by using setState function in the existing child, but it doesn't work.
I don't know why it's not working.
My assumption was that, if I change the task.completed and call the setState function, It will understand task.complete is dirty and refresh the objects related with.
Here's my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            child: AnimatedList(
              key: _listKey,
              initialItemCount: _data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I build AnimatedList calling _buildItem

```
 Widget _buildItem(Widget item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(sizeFactor: animation, child: item);
  }
```

In the buildItem it gives animation to item

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data.add(GestureDetector(
      child: Text(
        "Add",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _onButtonPress();
        });
      },
    ));
  }
```

In the initState function I added an item on the list which will be "existing item".

```
void _onButtonPress() {
    // replace this with method choice below
    _insertSingleItem();
  }
```

```
void _insertSingleItem() {
    int insertIndex = _data.length - 1;
    Widget widget = Form(
      child: TextField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        onEditingComplete: () {
          Task task = Task(name: textEditingController.text, completed: false);
          print(identityHashCode(task));
          tasks.add(task);
          print(identityHashCode(tasks.last));
          Widget taskWidget = GestureDetector(
            child: Text(
              task.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: task.completed ? Colors.grey : Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                print(identityHashCode(task));
                task.completed = !task.completed;
                bool temp = task.completed;
                print('$temp');
              }
              );
            },
          );
          setState(() {
            _data.removeAt(insertIndex);
            _data.insert(insertIndex, taskWidget);
            textEditingController.clear();
          });
        },
        showCursor: false,
      ),
    );
    _data.insert(insertIndex, widget);
    _listKey.currentState
        .insertItem(insertIndex, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
```

The problem occurs here. in the Gesturedetector, I want to change color itself by tapping it. I checked the value color changes by using print and it was changing from true to false when i tapping the child.
I don't understand why setState cannot change the dirty children, It knows task.completed is changed and so it is dirty.
please someone help me. I have been struggled with this problem on 3 days....

-----------------edited-----------------
I solved this problem by separating widget like this.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({this.task});
  Task task;
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState(task: task);
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Task task;

  _TestState({this.task});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            task.completed = !task.completed;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          task.name,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: task.completed ? Colors.grey[400] : Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 20.0),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

But still I don't understand why it works.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `UniqueKey` to each item in the list? in Stateful widgets sometimes you need to specify the item in a list because Flutter tries to rebuild as little as possible, so if there are any similar widgets, it will reuse instead of rebuild. Using a key will tell flutter that its a completely new widget and force a complete rebuild

Comment: just adding key: UniqueKey() to GestureDetector would be fine? I tried this just now it won't affect to the result.

Comment: I added UniqueKey() to widget everywhere I can add. but still not working... it might not a solution.